# Strange console output with Jasmine 2.0 using GruntJS (grunt-contrib-jasmine)

Tags: jasmine

I have added a spec as first of three in a describe block. When it is the only spec in that block, I get the following output:

```
updateTimerDisplay
 - calls removeCountdownTimer($widget) if no seconds are remaining...     SlideshowHome
```

(no checkmark or cross, but a minus sign in the beginning of the line and the final line break missing, so the title of the next describe block follows in the same output line)

when I disable that spec (with xit(...)), I get this output:

```
updateTimerDisplay
 * calls removeCountdownTimer($widget) if no seconds are remaining
```

but when I enable it together with the other specs, the output of the first spec is missing completely, but it is counted in the final specs count output from the jasmine task run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I fixed it by removing an underscore dependency in my vendors option. It may have something to do with grunt-contrib-jasmine using lodash.